# Security Exception while using Android DownloadManager.enqueue()

Tags: android, kotlin, android-download-manager, securityexception

Getting error :

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider uri content://downloads/my_downloads from pid=3608, uid=10081 requires android.permission.INTERNET, or grantUriPermission()
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:183)
        at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
        at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:476)
        at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:1274)
        at android.app.DownloadManager.enqueue(DownloadManager.java:1014)
        at com.udacity.MainActivity.startDownload(MainActivity.kt:124)
        at com.udacity.MainActivity.download(MainActivity.kt:96)
        at com.udacity.MainActivity.onCreate$lambda-0(MainActivity.kt:52)
        at com.udacity.MainActivity.$r8$lambda$3NfQc1qKvvShQbwLc_qeJ0be78s(MainActivity.kt)
        at com.udacity.MainActivity$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.onClick(D8$$SyntheticClass)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
In MainActivity : downloadManager.enqueue(request)
```

**Method to call DownloadManager to start Download file**

kotlin

```
private fun startDownload() { 

custom_button.buttonState = ButtonState.Clicked

val request = DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url)) .setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))

.setDescription(getString(R.string.app_description))

.setAllowedOverMetered(true)

.setAllowedOverRoaming(true)

val downloadManager = getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE) as DownloadManager downloadID = downloadManager.enqueue(request)// enqueue puts the download request in the queue.

}
```

**In Manifest using :**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permision.INTERNET"/>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and post the entire stack trace, not just the error message.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadStorageProvider requires android.permission.MANAGE\_DOCUMENTS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51139191/permission-denial-reading-com-android-providers-downloads-downloadstorageprovid)

Comment: Do you have WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking if you have these permissions in your manifest.

I'm not sure if this method will work above Android 10 since Scoped Storage was implemented. Learn more about it here ->
https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage

Also check out this answer for more help -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/68627407/19652887

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" 
    android:maxSdkVersion="28"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

If these are in your manifest, try checking for them on Runtime

***Kotlin ->***

```kotlin
var isReadPermissionAllowed = false
var isWritePermissionAllowed = false

isReadPermissionAllowed = 
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

isWritePermissionAllowed = 
ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

if (isReadPermissionAllowed && isWritePermissionAllowed) {
            startDownload()
        }else{
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                this,
                arrayOf(
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
                    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                ),1)
        }
```